# ASP.NET 5 project dependency cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a solution with 2 projects and I want to add a project reference pointing to my Core project

[image]

I get an error message

> The dependency Yugasat.Core>=4.0.0-* cannot be resolved

Here is the dependencies section in my project.json file

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `[4.0,5.0)` Can you try this for dependency versioning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the project reference incorrect.

> Project references are resolved using peer folders to the current project or project paths specified using a global.json file at the solution level

Check the documentation [link](http://dotnet.today/en/aspnet5-vnext/dnx/overview.html#dependencies) about how to reference project dependencies.

**Update**

I've updated the link.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: And now it's not! Thanks!